# iOS 17 horizontal scroll in browser

Tags: css, ios, safari, webkit, horizontal-scrolling

I've noticed that the horizontal scroll on a website I'm working on is no longer working properly since I've updated my iPhone to iOS 17. It's only working when swiping from the right screen corner to the left, not when swiping in the middle of the screen. Tested on an iPhone 13 Pro with iOS 17 and on Safari and Chrome Mobile.
On devices with <= iOS 16, it seems to work fine.

Has anyone experienced the same and/or may know a fix for this?

The code is quite standard for the behavior.
The container has `overflow: hidden` and the child has `overflow-x: scroll`.

Comment: Are you  using any <video> tags inside your scrollable container? There seems to be a bug with them in Safari on IOS 17: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77433898/cant-scroll-my-web-page-by-dragging-tapping-the-video-area-in-ios-sarafi/77495537#77495537